# Deserialize a binary tree breadth-first in Functional Programming

Tags: scala, functional-programming, binary-tree, breadth-first-search, construction

I had an imperative program which deserializes to a Binary Tree from an array. Its a BFS algorithm. I was wondering how to do this in Scala with functional programming concepts.

```
class TreeNode(_value: Int = 0, _left: TreeNode = null, _right: TreeNode = null) {
  val value: Int = _value
  val left: TreeNode = _left
  val right: TreeNode = _right
}
def createTree(list: Array[Int]): TreeNode = ???
```

For reference this is the imperative version in Javascript. The algorithm is described here. https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011883654-What-does-1-null-2-3-mean-in-binary-tree-representation-

```
class TreeNode {
  constructor(val){
    this.val = val;
    this.left = this.right = null;
  }
}

function makeTree(arr){
  let root = new TreeNode(arr[0]);
  let q = [root];

  let index = 1;
  while(q.length){
    let node = q.splice(0,1)[0];
    if(arr[index] != null){
      node.left = new TreeNode(arr[index]);
      q.push(node.left);
    }
    index++;

    if(arr[index] != null){
      node.right = new TreeNode(arr[index]);
      q.push(node.right);
    }
    index++;
  }
  return root;
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347337

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement breadth first search in Scala with FP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41347337/how-to-implement-breadth-first-search-in-scala-with-fp)

Comment: I disagree. This is not a duplicate of the suggested linked question and should not be closed. The linked question is about searching an existing tree. This question is about _building_ a tree from a breadth-first data description. Not the same thing.

Comment: The question is a about building a tree from an array than to iterate or search the tree.

Comment: [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60561480/849891) an answer in Haskell (and Prolog). :) depending on your representation, the building of the tree from its bfs sequence can be a no-op. e.g. when you use an array-backed representation.

Comment: @user I don't really speak no read no Scala unfortunately. :( I faked an answer once or twice I think, but that's it.) But really it's just filling in the structure. It's only cumbersome if your language has no mutation, like Haskell. Does Scala have mutation? Can you set a "field" of your "record" to a new value? then it's not a problem.

Comment: @user interesting, thanks. superficially reading it, that snippet does seem to follow the Haskell code (that was @ dfeuer's re-write BTW). Maybe Scala doesn't do lazy patterns like Haskell does (those `~`s)? in general `let ~(a: ~(b:c)) = t in ...a...b...c...` is the same as `... (head t)...(head (tail t)).... (tail (tail t))....`. maybe re-writing it in that vein will help?

Comment: @WillNess You were right, it does have to do with those irrefutable patterns. There are [workarounds](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MYHzLlf6RA2P0055JyDJQQ), but man, does it look ugly. Thanks for the ideas anyways

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can use a case class to simplify your tree class, and you should use `Option` instead of `null`:

```
case class Tree(value: Int, left: Option[Tree], right: Option[Tree])
```

Next, the main trouble here is because your tree is immutable, it needs to be built with a depth-first post-order traversal, and your serialization format requires a breadth-first level-order traversal. So you first have to deserialize to a data structure that can then be traversed in depth-first order. The following uses a Map from (row, column) to the node value:

```scala
@scala.annotation.tailrec
private def bfsTraverse(
    serialized: List[Option[Int]],
    queue: Queue[(Int, Int)],
    map: Map[(Int, Int), Int]): Map[(Int, Int), Int] = {
  val ((row, col), queueTail) = queue.dequeue
  if (serialized.isEmpty) {
    map
  } else if (serialized.head.isEmpty) {
    bfsTraverse(serialized.tail, queueTail, map)
  } else {
    val newQueue = queueTail.enqueueAll(List((row + 1, col * 2), (row + 1, col * 2 + 1)))
    val newMap = map + ((row, col) -> serialized.head.get)
    bfsTraverse(serialized.tail, newQueue, newMap)
  }
}
```

Now you can use the output of that function to build your `Tree`:

```scala
private def buildTree(row: Int, col: Int, map: Map[(Int, Int), Int]): Option[Tree] = {
  map.get((row, col)).map{value =>
    Tree(value, buildTree(row + 1, col * 2, map), buildTree(row + 1, col * 2 + 1, map))
  }
}
```

Comment: Pretty nice approach

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a bit verbose but uses some functional concepts and defines the data structures thoroughly.

- The algorithm you provided works better with mutable nodes. It's possible to have a shorter solution with just one mutable class, but here, there are two versions (one node class with mutable left/right and the other completely immutable).
- [Case classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) automatically provide a lot of useful features such as comparison and friendly print-out
- The `processValues` function tail-recursively performs the tasks equivalent to the `makeTree` function you provided.
- The [@tailrec](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/annotation/tailrec.html) annotation tells the compiler to check that the function is tail recursive.
- Pattern matching using the `match` and `case` keywords replace checking for null-ness or different subtypes, and the compiler can check for a non-exhaustive match clause.
- The [App](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/App.html) trait allows you to easily make an object (static class) into an entrypoint to run some examples.

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec

sealed trait TreeNode[T]
sealed trait MutableTreeNode[T]
object MutableTreeNode {
  final case class Empty[T]() extends MutableTreeNode[T]
  case class Branch[T](val value: T) extends MutableTreeNode[T] {
    protected var left: MutableTreeNode[T] = Empty()
    protected var right: MutableTreeNode[T] = Empty()
    def setLeft(newLeft: T): Branch[T] = {
      left = Branch(newLeft)
      left.asInstanceOf[Branch[T]] // shouldn't be necessary but compiler requires it
    }
    def setRight(newRight: T): Branch[T] = {
      right = Branch(newRight)
      right.asInstanceOf[Branch[T]]
    }
    override def toString: String = this.toImmutable().toString

    /* converts given node to immutable version */
    private def toImmutable(node: MutableTreeNode[T]): TreeNode[T] = {
      node match {
        case Empty() => TreeNode.Empty()
        case b@Branch(value) => TreeNode.Branch(value, toImmutable(b.left), toImmutable(b.right))
      }
    }
    def toImmutable():TreeNode[T] = toImmutable(this)
  }

  /**
    * Modifies nodes inside of queue
    */
  @tailrec def processValues[T](values: Seq[Option[T]], queue: Seq[MutableTreeNode.Branch[T]]): Unit = {
    (queue, values) match {
      case (Nil, _) => ()
      case (_, Nil) => ()
      case (qHead :: qTail, Some(vLeft) :: Some(vRight) :: vTail) =>
        processValues(vTail, qTail :+ qHead.setLeft(vLeft) :+ qHead.setRight(vRight))
      case (qHead :: qTail, Some(vLeft) :: None :: vTail) =>
        processValues(vTail, qTail :+ qHead.setLeft(vLeft))
      case (qHead :: qTail, None :: Some(vRight) :: vTail) =>
        processValues(vTail, qTail :+ qHead.setRight(vRight))
      case (qHead :: qTail, None :: None :: vTail) =>
        processValues(vTail, qTail)
    }
  }
}
object TreeNode {
  final case class Empty[T]() extends TreeNode[T]
  final case class Branch[T](value: T, left: TreeNode[T], right: TreeNode[T]) extends TreeNode[T]

  def deserialize[T](values: Seq[Option[T]]): TreeNode[T] = {
    values match {
      case Some(headVal) :: tail =>
        val root: MutableTreeNode.Branch[T] = MutableTreeNode.Branch(headVal)
        MutableTreeNode.processValues(tail, Seq(root))
        root.toImmutable()
      case Nil => Empty()
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Invalid argument values")
    }
  }
}

object TreeNodeTest extends App {
  val input = Seq(Some(5), Some(4), Some(7), None, None, Some(2), None)
  val treeNode:TreeNode[Int] = TreeNode.deserialize(input)
  println(treeNode)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted, Scala avoids `null` whenever possible, preferring `Option` to indicate the absence of a value.

Mutable variables are also shunned, which makes it much easier to construct a B-tree in a depth-first manner rather than breadth-first.

So all you really need is an easy-to-use breadth-first-serialization --to--> depth-first-serialization translator.

I did it in two steps.

```
//from Breadth-First-Serialization to full tree representation
def BFS2full[A](bfs:IndexedSeq[Option[A]]) :List[List[Option[A]]] = {
  val bfsLen = bfs.length
  if (bfs.isEmpty) Nil
  else
    List(bfs.head) :: List.unfold((List(bfs.head),1)){case (pr,idx) =>
      Option.when(bfsLen > idx){
        val ns = pr.foldLeft((List.empty[Option[A]],idx)){
          case ((acc,x), None) => (acc ++ List(None,None), x)
          case ((acc,x), _) => (acc ++ List(bfs.lift(x).flatten
                                           ,bfs.lift(x+1).flatten), x+2)
        }
        (ns._1, ns)
      }
    }
}

//from full tree representation to Depth-First-Serialization
def toDFS[A](lloa :List[List[Option[A]]]
            ,lvl :Int = 0) :List[Option[A]] = lloa match {
  case Nil => List(None, None)
  case List(None) :: Nil => List(None)
  case List( oa ) :: tl  => oa :: toDFS(tl, lvl)
  case row :: tl => row.drop(lvl*2) match {
    case List(None,None,_*) => List(None, None)
    case List(None, ob ,_*) => None :: (ob::toDFS(tl,2*lvl + 1))
    case List( oa ,None,_*) => (oa::toDFS(tl,2*lvl)) ++ List(None)
    case List( oa , ob ,_*) => (oa :: toDFS(tl, 2*lvl)) ++
                                (ob :: toDFS(tl,2*lvl + 1))
  }
}
```

Now let's parameterize the tree so that we can build `Int` trees, `Float` trees, `String` trees, etc.

We're also going to make the constructor `private` so that node creation is only done via factory methods.

```
case class Tree[A] private (value : A
                           ,left  : Option[Tree[A]]
                           ,right : Option[Tree[A]])
```

All that's left is to supply the factory methods.

```
object Tree {
  private def BFS2full[A]( . . . //as above 
  private def toDFS[A]( . . . //as above

  def fromDFS[A](dfs :IterableOnce[Option[A]]) :Option[Tree[A]] = {
    val itr = dfs.iterator
    def loop(): Option[Tree[A]] =
      Option.when(itr.hasNext)(itr.next())
            .flatten
            .map(new Tree(_,loop(),loop()))
    loop()
  }
  def fromBFS[A](bfs:IndexedSeq[Option[A]]) :Option[Tree[A]] =
    fromDFS(toDFS(BFS2full(bfs)))
}
```

testing:

```
Tree.fromBFS(Vector(Some('A'),None,Some('B'),Some('C'))).get
//res0: Tree[Char] = Tree(A,None,Some(Tree(B,Some(Tree(C,None,None)),None)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic solution. It doesn't use lazy vals or any data structures other than `List`, `Option`, and `Either`. You might find it easier to understand because of that or harder because of the verbosity.

I've defined `Tree` like this, just to make things easier.

```
sealed trait Tree[+T]
case class Node[+T](data: T, left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]
case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]
```

Also, instead of an `Array[Int]`, I'm using a `List[Option[T]]` (where `T` is a type parameter of the `makeTree` method). `Some` means there's a node, `None` is like `-1` in your code. This is more idiomatic and also works for types other than `Int`.

---

The thing about doing this breadth-first is that you need to kinda keep passing the input list around to the children. First you try to make the left child, then when that's done, you try make the right child. Then you try to make the left child's children, then the right child's children, then their children, and so on.

One way to deal this without using `var` would be to take in the input list containing the serialized binary tree and see what the head of the list is. If it's a `None`, we can just return an `Empty`, because we know it's the end of the tree. If it's a `Some` however, we can't yet return a tree, but we can return *another* function that takes in the next round of input and returns a tree.

Since there are 2 different types that can be returned, these functions will be of type `List[Option[T]] => Either[List[Option[T]] => ThisFunctionsType, Tree[T]]`. Since the function may return another function of the same type, we'll have to define a new type that can return itself:

```
trait RecFun[T] extends ((List[Option[T]]) => (List[Option[T]], Either[RecFun[T], Tree[T]]))
```

The reason that it's `List[Option[T]] => (List[Option[T]], Either[RecFun[T], Tree[T]])` and not just `List[Option[T]] => Either[RecFun[T], Tree[T]]` is that in case one child turns out to be a leaf somewhere in the middle of the list, we still need to continue, so the first element of the returned tuple contains the rest of the list after processing.

Now we can define this. The `helper` function is so that as long as the `RecFun` returns a `Left[RecFun]`, it keeps passing the remaining input into that function.

```
def makeTree[T](list: List[Option[T]]): Tree[T] = {
  def helper(f: RecFun[T], l: List[Option[T]]): Tree[T] =
    f(l) match {
      case (_, Right(tree)) => tree
      case (next, Left(f))  => helper(f, next)
    }

  list match {
    case Some(x) :: tail => helper(createRec(x), tail)
    case _               => Empty
  }
}

def createRec[T](data: T): RecFun[T] = {
  case None :: Nil | Nil => (Nil, Right(Node(data, Empty, Empty)))
  case Some(l) :: Nil => (Nil, Right(Node(data, Node(l, Empty, Empty), Empty)))
  case lo :: ro :: rest =>
    (rest, (lo, ro) match {
      case (Some(l), Some(r)) =>
        Left(waitForChildren(data, createRec(l), createRec(r)))
      case (Some(l), None) =>
        Left(waitForChild(Node(data, _, Empty), createRec(l)))
      case (None, Some(r)) =>
        Left(waitForChild(Node(data, Empty, _), createRec(r)))
      case (None, None) => Right(Node(data, Empty, Empty))
    })
  }

def waitForChildren[T](data: T, leftF: RecFun[T], rightF: RecFun[T]): RecFun[T] =
  input => {
    val (next, res) = leftF(input)
    res match {
      case Right(tree) =>
        (next, Left(waitForChild(Node(data, tree, _), rightF)))
      case Left(leftF2) => {
        val (next2, res2) = rightF(next)
        (next2, Left(res2 match {
          case Right(tree)   => waitForChild(Node(data, _, tree), leftF2)
          case Left(rightF2) => waitForChildren(data, leftF2, rightF2)
        }))
      }
    }
  }

def waitForChild[T](ctor: Tree[T] => Node[T], f: RecFun[T]): RecFun[T] =
  input => {
    val (next, res) = f(input)
    (next, res match {
      case Right(tree)  => Right(ctor(tree))
      case Left(recFun) => Left(waitForChild(ctor, recFun))
    })
  }
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ysthakur/zbz0g71sSyO2nf64TUaxWw/2)